# A 2-d numpy ndarray showing 1-d shape

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, word2vec

I am getting a numpy array from the following function

```
def get_word_vec_norm(post):
    doc = nlp(post)
    word_vec = []
    index = 1
    for token in doc:
        word_vec.append(token.vector_norm)
        index = index + 1
        if index>2:
            break
#     return word_vec
    return np.asarray(word_vec)
```

after the calling this function

```
X = data['cleaned_post'].apply(get_word_vec_norm)
```

Now, I was expecting shape of X is `(18,2)` but it showing `(18, 1)` as shown in following image. 
[image]

I think I have done something wrong somewhere. Would anyone please correct me. I would be thankful. thank you.

Comment: can you post the `X` as code?

Comment: If `data` is a DataFrame, then the apply should return a new dataframe or series.  Is `X` that Series, or its `values`.  Each element of the Series is this 2 element array.  The result is an object dtype array containing arrays. I'm puzzled as to why the shape is (10,1) as opposed to (10,).

Comment: `np.stack(X)` or maybe `np.stack(X.ravel())` should join the arrays into one 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload the matrix `X` or the `DataFrame`, I could provide a more details answer.

In the function you use `word_vec.append(token.vector_norm)` so you append elements into a list.

and then you do: `np.asarray(word_vec)`, i.e. you convert the list into numpy array

This lead to the observed output.

Comment: Yes, `word_vec` is a list (of 2 floats). But `np.asarray()` will return an array. It does **not** "store a list of arrays into a big array" – that happens as a result of the `apply()`, and I suspect that has more to do with `pandas` implied-types for the result of the `apply()`.

Comment: `np.asarray()` in this case convert the list into numpy array (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html)

Comment: Yes, it converts the list of 2 floats into a single 1d array with 2 elements – not "a list of arrays into a big array".

Comment: @gojomo, why do you think the shape is (10,1) as opposed to (10,)?

Comment: @hpaulj I'm not sure, but strongly suspect the key is the type-handling and return-shape behavior of `pandas` `apply()` function. So I added the `pandas` tag in hopes true Pandas experts may chime in.